# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "print" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\variables.php on line 14 when following book PHP for the Web,4th edition

Tags: php, html, parsing, printing

I am following the steps in the book PHP for the Web, 4th edition. I am using Dreamweaver for my IDE. The author is using XHTML where I am using HTML5. I followied exactly what he is doing but when sending it to the server I get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "print" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\variables.php on line 14.
Here is the code:

```
<?php // Script 2.3 - variables.php
$street = "100 Main Street"
$city = "State College";
$state = "PA";
$zip = 16801
print "<p>The address is:<br/>$street <br/>$city $state $zip</p>";
?>
```

Line 14 is the print function line. I've tried placing the quotations elsewhere, I've tried following the W3Schools tutorial and get this error still. What is the problem?

Comment: What PHP sees is `$zip = 16801 print …`. No separator between statements. Use a real IDE, not Dreamweaver.

Comment: So switch to a different IDE and run the same code?

Comment: I tried adding the semi-colon to the end of $zip= 16801 but received the same error along with another error about the semi-colon. Still confused here.

Comment: It's not the only missing semicolon.

Comment: @mario Thank you for pointing this out. I feel a little embarrassed because I have tried everything and all it was is a missing semi-colon, lol! Thank you!